# problem with services in automatic restart

Tags: oracle, sqlplus

I am working on Oracle 19c. I have a problem with the services I created via:

```
alter system set service_names=' exemple1, exemple2' scope=both;
```

I have many services to create and I am limited to 255 characters, so I can't put all services  on one line, and if I divide the line by all my services, only the services of the last command take the option: `scope=both`

Can someone please help me?

---

Thank you for your answer, my problem is not with the service_name parameter because my services have been created.

My problem is that I have 128 services to create and via sqlplus when I type:

alter system set service_names='service1, service2 , service3 … service 128' scope=both;

I have an oracle error that I exceeded the 255 character

So I cut in several times:

alter system set service_names='service1, service2 , service3 …' scope=both;

alter system set service_names='service4, service5, service6 … service' scope=both;

alter system set service_names='service7, service8 , service9 … service' scope=both;

alter system set service_names='service10, service11 , service12 … service128' scope=both;

My services are all present, but my problem is that it looks like the scope=both only applies to the last line, so I only have the services of the last line which are autostarted

Comment: What makes you think you are "limited to 255 characters"?

Comment: That parameter is deprecated https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/refrn/SERVICE_NAMES.html#GUID-AC956707-D568-4F8A-BF2E-99BA41E0A64F tells you what to do instead

Comment: by issuing that command several times, you overwrite it every time. The end result will be that your database only recognises the services that are in the last command. You did not say what type of environment you have - only datafiles on disk, or ASM/Restart or RAC?